# First visible UITableView rows not showing data when loading...but then do on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITable which shows the 10 most recent images from a web service. Each row has its own image. When the UITable first loads in the viewcontroller it doesnt show the first 4 images in the rows (screen is blank). If I scroll down the last 6 images appear....then if I scroll back the first 4 images that were NOT there originally DO appear and everything looks the way I wanted it to initially.  My guess is its something do with the way cells are reused.

Here is my tableView code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
    [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[self.photoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved my issue was adding the following line to my method that deals with streaming the photos from the Web API:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I moved the Table View Cell up or down in the its Table View at the Storyboard  that changed the position of the invisible row as well. So I solved the problem by setting the Table View Cell as hidden.

Comment: try adding some relevant part of the code in your answer to make it clearer.